# Create a competition with national teams and clubs

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-2013

I'm trying to play a competition where national teams and clubs are allowed to play **in a single group** of 15+, home and away (a league like competition which includes national teams too)

I remember I was able to do that in some old version of PES, I wasn't able to find it PES2013 (Konami cup doesn't allow such thing)

So, what I'm asking is; is this possible in PES2013 or no need to search more?